# Which MySQL query is best for getting data from two tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, myisam

I have two tables like this:

```
mysql> desc table1;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc table2;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

ID field is same in both tables for their respective data.

DB engine : MYISAM

I would like to get data from both tables, and I have been trying various queries for that.,

All the following queries work fine, but I would like to know the best query as per the performance wise, table contains 20 million+ records.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT t2.age, t1.name
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id =1
AND t2.id =1
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT table1.name, age
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id =1
AND table2.id =1
```

**Query 3**

```
SELECT  table1.name , table2.age 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = 1 
AND table2.id = 1
```

**Query 4**

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.age
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.id =1
AND table2.id =1
```

**Query 5**

```
SELECT table1.name, age
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id =1
AND table2.id =1
```

So which one is best to use for high load/traffic site? best for performance wise?

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick comment. In your queries 1 & 4, you already defined a relationship `t1.id=12.id`, so it is redundant to specify both `t1.id=1` and `t2.id=1`. One of these statements is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid a full table scan on table2 I would recommend you to add an index on "table2.id" field, then you can perform an "explain" and see which of them is better.

As you described all your queries will perform pretty much the same, BUT without adding the index on table2 all the records on that table will be read. Try out that and compare with your current results timing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from the both tables, and  get data only if `id = 1`, you can use limit 1 and NOT `WHERE table1.id =1 AND table2.id =1`.

You want to get data if the same id is exists in 2 tables you should `INNER JOIN` your tables

```
SELECT t2.age, t1.name
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT t2.age, t1.name
FROM table2 t2, table 1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Some database engines optimize joins better, so I'd go with your first suggestion.

Comment: @Racil Hilan: joins better than *what*? The second is an inner join written implicitly. Most DB engines would transform the 1st query into second before performing.

Comment: @zerkms Oh, my bad. I was reading several posts and typed my comment into the wrong one. You're absolutely right here, there is no difference in performance between the two suggestions above. Some people prefer one over the other. However, explicit joins give clearer intent as they represent semantic relationships between two sets of data, while `WHERE` suggests a filtered set. But database engines translate them to the same plan, as you pointed out.

Comment: @Racil Hilan: indeed. Personally I don't see a reason to use an implicit form as well.

Comment: @user2022549 Are your suggestions missing the sorting? 'ORDER BY t1.id`. Otherwise, how is `LIMIT 1` guaranteed to get that specific row?

Comment: How I know all engines automatically sort by primary key by ASC, in this case the engine should transform this query to ORDER BY t1.id ASC LIMIT 1 and output the data there is the t1.id is 1.